# ExcelResponse doesn't send file correctly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-excel

I'm using django-excel-response 2.0.5 to download Excel sheet using Django.

```
sheet = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
response = ExcelResponse(sheet, 'test')
return response
```

Instead of downloading file, it doesn't open anything and response.data is byte version of file, like
`PK�����5���� ��GEp,���L�v��>�ݾ��cb�x����Ш=���0����E  &o��PK`
Is there a problem in Django rest settings, or I'm using lib wrong?

I tried to change view class, different response classes, but nothing helped

Comment: Is it maybe just missing a content disposition? If you save the response as a file, and rename it to xlsx, does it open in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Bytes shown are likely to come from ZIP files.

Office OpenXML format is a ZIP file of several XML files. So by renaming the file as XLSX you should be able to read it.

If you want to get directly XLSX files you should define content disposition and type in your header.